# C# net core api post json request body is empty

Tags: c#, nginx, asp.net-core

I have this sample code.

```
 [HttpPost("TelegramWebHook")] 
    public IActionResult TelegramWebHook()
    {
        var output = "";

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
        {
            output = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return Ok(output);
    }
```

I use Postman for POST JSON. Debug on local machine work fine. On Linux, output var is empty.

I use nginx proxy to kestrel server.

UPDATE
Same code on IIS with net core, working.

Comment: Why can't you pass the data as parameter to the Action?

Comment: Because the client is not me. Performs a simple POST with a json in the body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This working!

```
[HttpPost("TelegramWebHookOpenload")]
    public IActionResult TelegramWebHook([FromBody] JObject mydata)
    {
        var output = "";

        output = mydata.ToString();

        return Ok(output);
    }
```

I add `[FromBody] JObject mydata`